# Jquery Function add class and remove class on multiple buttons but only execute specific button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I seem to be stuck on this certain code. I have multiple buttons on my website that when you click one, it changes classes & the text inside then revert back after clicking again. It seems to only work on one button but there are multiples of buttons with the same ID & when they are clicked nothing happens. Heres the codeenter code here

```
$('#btnInfo').click(function() 
{ 
  if ($(this).text() == "More Info") 
  { 
     $(this).text("Cancel").addClass('btn-danger'); 
  } 
  else 
  { 
     $(this).text("More Info").removeClass('btn-danger'); 
  }; 
});
```

Im not to sure only one button gets the function while the others stay the same when i click them but I want all the buttons to execute the code above but onlt to the button i specifically clicked with the ID

Comment: Add your html to the question. It looks like you are attaching this function to an Id, so it would work for only the button with the id: "btnInfo"

Comment: "there are multiples of buttons with the same ID" it is not good

Comment: do not use "multiples of buttons with the same ID" - this is against html specification and selector '#btnInfo' will return only the first element it finds. Give these buttons the same class and search by it: '.buttonClass' - this class does not even have to exist.

Comment: if it is multiple buttons it should not be an ID anymore, then you give should give them a class. f.ex class="btnInfo" and to referer to them in javascript the selector is $('.btnInfo')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you cannot have more than one element with the same "ID", so use class instead.
I think what you want is to bind the event click to all your buttons, do this instead.

```
$('.className').on('click', function(e){
    if ($(this).text() == "More Info") 
    { 
        $(this).text("Cancel").addClass('btn-danger'); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $(this).text("More Info").removeClass('btn-danger'); 
    }; 
});
```

Check the link for more info : http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: why is `.on(` better than `.click(` in this case?

Comment: .on("click") is the same as .click()

Comment: it is not better, it is the same because click() is a shortcut of on('click')

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are looking exactly
If you are looking for this functionality for all the buttons, you need something like this.

```
$('button').click(function()  //see changed css selector
{ 
  if ($(this).text() == "More Info") 
  { 
     $(this).text("Cancel").addClass('btn-danger'); 
  } 
  else 
  { 
     $(this).text("More Info").removeClass('btn-danger'); 
  }; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is an id #btnInfo in the below line

```
$('#btnInfo').click(function()
```

This will select only one button. Use a class, .btnInfo and add it as class attribute to the buttons